# Composition of Readers for Dependency Injection in Scala

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, composition, scala-cats, reader-monad

Here is a simple service example, whose methods return reader:

```
trait Service1_1{
  def s1f1:Reader[Map[String,Int],Int] =
    Reader(_("name"))

  def s1f2:Reader[Map[String,Int],Int] =
    Reader(_("age"))
}
```

Here is a service-consumer, that accepts parameter, map, and also returns reader itself:

```
trait Service1_2 {
  def s12f1(i:Int, map:Map[String,Int]):Reader[Service1_1, Int] =
    Reader(s => {
      val r = for {
        r1 <- s.s1f1
        r2 <- s.s1f2
      } yield r1 + r2
      r.run(map) + i
    })
}
```

Ok, to use Service1_2.s12f1 I must have map in the parameter list:

```
object s1 extends Service1_1
object s2 extends Service1_2
val r = s2.s12f1(3, Map("age"-> 1, "name"-> 2)).run(s1)
```

The question: how to implement `Service1_2.s12f2`:

```
trait Service1_2 {
  def s2f2 = ???
}
```

In order to be able to run it like:

```
s2.s2f2(2)
  .run(s1)
  .run(Map("age"-> 1, "name"-> 2))
```

The main idea is to postpone passing of dependency to the execution. This should allow to get a better composition and deferred execution. How to get it work? What are the best practices with Readers, in case there are nested calls with such dependencies. For instance, imagine service, `Service1_3`, which in one method, will use both `Service1_2.s2f2` and `Service1_1.s1f1`

**UPDATE**, ok, I could implement it, but it looks, over complicated:

```
  def s2f2(i:Int): Reader[Service1_1, Reader[Map[String,Int],Int]] =
    Reader(s => Reader(map => {
      val r = for {
        r1 <- s.s1f1
        r2 <- s.s1f2
      } yield r1 + r2
      r.run(map) + i
    }))
```

The question, is there a better approach? Or at least syntax? Cause with several levels of dependency, it will look strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably "uncurry" the reader, so that instead of having two (or more) layers of readers, I'd have an n-tuple as the environment. Then you can "raise" smaller readers into the current level with `local`.

For example, instead of `Reader[Service1_1, Reader[Map[String, Int], Int]]` I'd use `Reader[(Service1_1, Map[String, Int]), Int]`:

```
import cats.data.Reader

trait Service1_1{
  def s1f1: Reader[Map[String, Int], Int] = Reader(_("name"))
  def s1f2: Reader[Map[String, Int], Int] = Reader(_("age"))
}

trait Service1_2 {
  type Env = (Service1_1, Map[String,Int])

  def s2f2(i: Int): Reader[Env, Int] =
    for {
      s <- Reader((_: Env)._1)
      r1 <- s.s1f1.local((_: Env)._2)
      r2 <- s.s1f2.local((_: Env)._2)
    } yield r1 + r2 + i
}
```

And then:

```
scala> object s1 extends Service1_1
defined object s1

scala> object s2 extends Service1_2
defined object s2

scala> s2.s2f2(2).run((s1, Map("age"-> 1, "name"-> 2)))
res0: cats.Id[Int] = 5
```

This works exactly the same as your `s2f2` except that instead of `s2.s2f2(2).run(s1).run(myMap)` we write `s2.s2f2(2).run((s1, myMap))`, or even just `s2.s2f2(2).run(s1, myMap)` using adapted args.

The advantage of this approach is that even as you add layers, you can compose the new and previous readers in a single `for`-comprehension via `local`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Interesting point. Can you please explain a little bit, what does 'local' in the expression: 's.s1f1.local((_: Env)._2)' do?

Comment: @Alexandr It's like putting an operation before the reader function. It lets you "widen" e.g. a `Reader[A, B]` to a `Reader[(A, C), B]`.

Comment: thank you! It is really very useful to know. Can you recommend anything additionally to read, where such issues are described. Most articles about readers just show a basic case, which is so simple, but in practice cannot be used without knowing other possibilities.

Comment: I agree—in general there seem to be lots of introductory blog posts on Cats-related topics that don't do a very good job of introducing their topics. At a glance [this one](https://blog.ssanj.net/posts/2017-06-12-reading-configuration-with-kleisli-arrows.html) seems a little better than most?

Comment: There's also the `Kleisli` documentation: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html